# redis setup for python-eve

Tags: python, redis, eve

I was reading python-eve's [documentation](http://python-eve.org/features.html#rate-limiting) about rate limiting, looks like it is using redis to store the 'session info', however I cannot find the documentation about how to setup the connection to redis in python-eve? e.g. specify which server the redis is hosted etc? thanks

Answer (score 6):

You pass the redis instance to Eve, so you can configure it however you wish beforehand. I guess something like this should work:

```
import redis
from eve import Eve

r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

app = Eve(redis=r)
app.run()
```